# Filter injection with autofac in MVC3

Tags: autofac

I have a set of global filters, each derived from IGlobalFilter

```
//knows how to add itself in filter collection
abstract class GlobalFilter : IGlobalFilter {}

class MyFilter : GlobalFilter, IRequestFilter{}

public class GlobalFilterActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker {}
```

Here is my autofac registration

```
builder.RegisterType<MyFilter>().As<IGlobalFilter>();
builder.RegisterType<GlobalFilterActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker();
builder.RegisterControllers(assemblies).PropertiesAutoWired().InjectActionInvoker();
```

For what ever the reason my GlobalFilterActionInvoker's GetFilters method is not being called.

Constructors of these components are being called indicating that autofac registration is successful!

How can troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.  We are using Glimpse (server side debugger similar to firebug).  They have their own controllactioninvoker.  Which is overriding my autofac registration!!!

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Could you manage to get Autofac and Glimpse working together?

Comment: latest version of glimpse seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: Looks like it is broken again, using MVC4 and glimpse 0.87

Comment: Here are some issues regarding this on glimpse issues in github
https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/484 https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/328